# Relation between the decomposition invariants of a projective reduced curve and its normalization

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, algebraic-curves, projective-geometry

Let $X$ be a reduced projective scheme over $k$ which is of pure
dimension 1. Let $\pi: X \to \mathbb{P}_k^1$ be a finite (hence
affine, surjective and flat) morphism of schemes having degree
$n$. Since $X$ is Cohen-Macaulay, $\pi_*\mathcal{O}_X$ is a free
$\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}_k^1}$-module of finite rank $n$ and hence
decomposes into a direct sum of Serre's twisted sheaves:
$$
\pi_*\mathcal{O}_X \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^n \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}_k^1}(|\mathcal{O}_X|_i)
$$
The integers $|\mathcal{O}_X|_1 \geq \ldots \geq |\mathcal{O}_X|_n$
are uniquely determined by $\mathcal{O}_X$. Now we have a similar
situation for the structure sheaf of any irreducible component $X_i$ of
$X$: The closed immersion $j_i: X_i \to X$ is a finite morphism and
hence $\pi_i = \pi \circ j_i: X_i \to X \to \mathbb{P}_k^1$ is also
finite of degree $n_i < n$ if $X_i \neq X$. Hence
$$
(\pi_i)_*\mathcal{O}_{X_i} \cong \pi_* ((j_i)_* \mathcal{O}_{X_i}) \cong
\pi_* (\mathcal{O}_X / \mathcal{I}_i) \cong \bigoplus_{j=1}^{n_i}
\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}_k^1}(|\mathcal{O}_{X_i}|_j)
$$
where $\mathcal{I}_{X_i}$ denotes the ideal sheaf cutting out $X_i$ in
$X$.

Since $X$ is reduced, we have a finite morphism
$X' = \bigoplus_{i=1}^m X'_i \to X$ where $X'$ is the normalization of
$X$ (and $X_i'$ is the normalization of the component $X_i$) and a
corresponding injective morphism
$\mathcal{O}_X \hookrightarrow \bigoplus_{i=1}^n
\mathcal{O}_{X_i}/\mathcal{I}_i$
with finite index $\chi(\mathcal{S})$ where $\mathcal{S}$ makes the following sequence exact
$$
0 \to \mathcal{O}_X \hookrightarrow \bigoplus_{i=1}^n
\mathcal{O}_{X_i}/\mathcal{I}_i \to \mathcal{S} \to 0.
$$
It is not hard to see that 
$$
\pi_* \mathcal{O}_X \hookrightarrow \pi_*\left( \bigoplus_{i=1}^n \mathcal{O}_{X_i}/\mathcal{I}_i\right) \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^{m} \bigoplus_{j=1}^{n_i}
\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}_k^1}(|\mathcal{O}_{X_i}|_j).
$$

> **My question is:** What are the relations between
>   $L_{X'} := (|\mathcal{O}_{X_i}|_j)_{i,j}$ and $L_X := (|\mathcal{O}_{X}|_\ell)_\ell$ both
>   arranged in descending order? To be more specific: Does 
>   $$
> L_{X'}[i] - L_X[i] \in O\left( \frac{\chi(\mathcal{S})}{n}\right)
> $$
>   hold, i.e. are the differences balanced. Does someone know a good
>   read for this kind of situations or any references at all? Any good idea is also welcome.

*What I do know so far:*

1. $L_{X} \leq L_{X'}$, that is for all $i=1,\ldots,n : L_{X}[i] \leq L_{X'}[i]$,
2. $\sum_{\ell=1}^n |\mathcal{O}_{X}|_\ell = \chi(\mathcal{O}_X) -n$,
3. $\sum_{i,j} |\mathcal{O}_{X_i}|_j = \sum_{i=1}^m
     (\chi(\mathcal{O}_{X_i}) -n_i) = \chi(\mathcal{O}_X) +
     \chi(\mathcal{S}) -n$
4. Combining 2. and 3. we have: $\sum_{i=1}^n L_{X'}[i] - L_X[i] = \chi(\mathcal{S})$.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think there is no bound of the type you want. Namely, choose $X$ to be the nodal curve obtained by glueing $n$ copies $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ of the base $\mathbf{P}^1$ by glueing points as follows: first glue $X_3, \ldots, X_n$ each to $X_1$ in a single point, next glue $X_2$ to $X_1$ in $N$ distinct points. We assume the points we are glueing at map to $n - 2 + N$ pairwise distinct points in $\mathbf{P}^1$.

First we observe that $|\mathcal{O}_{X_i}|_j = 0$ always.

For a scheme $Z$ over $\mathbf{P}^1$ denote $\mathcal{O}_Z(i)$ the pullback of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbf{P}^1}(i)$ to $Z$.

Denote $X' \subset X$ the union of $X_1$ and $X_2$. A computation show that $H^1(X', \mathcal{O}_{X'}(N - 2))$ is nonzero. Since $\mathcal{O}_X(N - 2) \to \mathcal{O}_{X'}(N - 2)$ is surjective and since $X$ is a curve, we see that $H^1(\mathcal{O}_X(N - 2))$ is nonzero. This implies that $|\mathcal{O}_X|_n \leq -N$.

Comment: If I could follow your instructions correctly, then the
curve $X'$ you described is of the form $X' = V_+(F')
\subset \mathbb{P}_k^2$ with $F'$ being a homogeneous
polynomial of degree $N+1$. And we obtain $X$ as $V_+(F)
\subset \mathbb{P}_k^2$ where $F'$ divides $F$. In your
notation, we thus have $\deg F = \deg F' + n$.

Comment: (continued) 

The intended
bound is $-\chi(\mathcal{S})/\deg \pi =
-\chi(\mathcal{O}_X)/\deg F$. Now since $X$ is a local
complete intersection, we have $-\chi(\mathcal{O}_X) =
p_a(X) -1 = \frac{1}{2}(\deg F -1)(\deg F-2)-1 \in O(\deg
F^2)$. Moreover, $\deg \pi = \deg F$ and thus the intended
bound is in $O(\deg F)$.

But your argument is that we deduce $|X|_n \leq - \deg F' =
\deg F - n \leq -\chi(\mathcal{S})/\deg \pi$ which is still in the intended order.